# Is this site the proper SE site to ask for an app review?

Tags: discussion

I am writing a completely vanilla Javascript report writer. In brief, it allows for the creation of completely customizable reports, pageable output, and query interface to a php backend. It allows for binding to queries (result sets), calculated fields, grouping, etc.

The project is fairly extensive and I am at proof of concept stage where core functionality works. Is this the site to get feedback on the project? I am likely to release the code under an MPL 2.0 license. I am hoping for:

- A high level look at the architecture: interface, class structure, code, etc.
- Feedback on its potential usefulness.

I would give a link to a site with the app fully functional using a test MySql database with sample reports.

Code could be available on GitHub.

If this is not the site, where would you recommend?

Comment: see also: [Should a question that is meaningless without viewing an external link be closed?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266909/839601)

Answer (score 3):

Asking for a review of a whole project will result in a question that's way too broad for any Stack Exchange site.

The system works when you have a specific or fairly narrow question that can be answered in a few paragraphs. If you can write a chapter of a book or even a whole book in response to the question then it's not the sort of question we want.

If you have specific concerns about aspects of your design then those questions would be welcome here.

Comment: I figured that I would have to bring the scope down my inquiries to specific questions. Would it be appropriate to have the whole project and its code available as part of a question and, for example, Is it appropriate to ask for feedback on a user interface?

Comment: @mseifert you could include the link to the project, but some people might flag it as spam (it does happen), so be warned. Questions about UI design *might* be on topic on [ux.se], but check before posting.

Answer (score 0):

To get the best out of the stack* sites you will have to narrow down.  In your application I'm sure there are aspects about which you feel would need more attention or dont feel just right.  Expose your objective, explain your implementation and expose your theory as to what is wrong.  Does require more work than a simpler "is this good (link to source code)" but will get you immensly more constructive feedback too.

This will hold true pretty much regardless of the stack site you are posting to.